# Azure DevOps Extensions Copying value of one field to another field

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I am trying to create Azure DevOps extension where, I want to copy(assign) value of one field to another field when the System.State is "todo". Is there a way this can by achieved using onFieldChanged event in Azure DevOps?
As shown in the image attached, I want to display the text written in System.Title in System.Description using onChange event. Is it achievable using extension?
I followed Microsoft documentation on creating simple extension using html, JavaScript, vss-extension.json. Couldn't find how the events and fields works in extensions.

[image: Please find the image]

Answer (score 1):

We recommend that you use [custom rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/custom-rules?view=azure-devops) to copy value of one field to another field when the System.State is To Do.

Sample and result:

[image]

**Update1**

We can create extension to copy value of one field to another field. We can use onFieldChanged to get the field value and copy the value to another field. Here is an [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-workitem-extension?view=azure-devops#javascript-sample) to get work item detail via the event onFieldChanged, please check it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I am looking for a way to achieve it by using extensions for my requirement. Is it possible?

Comment: Hi @Jay K, I have updated the answer, please check. Using rules is the easiest way.